# Mongoose-Paginate - Sorting by a populated field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose-paginate to get a list of records sorted by a field which was populated from a reference.

```js
// models

const Company = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String
});

const report = new Schema({
  _company: { 
    type: String, 
    ref: 'Company' 
  },
  name: String
});

let options = {
  offset: 0,
  limit:10,
  populate: '_company',
  select: 'type _company',
  sort: { '_company.name': 1 },
  lean: true
};

// paginate.
report.paginate({},options, (err, results) =>  {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  
  res.jsonp({
    data: results
  });
})
```

Is there a way to sort by the field _company.name, which is a populated field.

added sample code below.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't perform a query on the populated field because the population "physically" happens after the query. Population is a mongoose feature, not mongoDB. A solution could be 2 queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to sort populated documents is to do it manually after you receive all results.

Or for the schema, you defined in the question you should make reports a subdocument in the company schema. like this.

```
const reportSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});


const companySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
    reports: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Report'
    }],

});

// we need to create a model to use it
var Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
var Report = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);
```

and user aggregate to sort and unwind the reports to list them all.

```
Comapnay.aggregate( [ { 
$match: { <whatever query you want to user> } },
{ $sort : { name : 1 } }
{ $unwind : "$reports" } ] )
```

Comment: Lookup aggregation is the join process of the Mongo. So that there is feature $lookup used to join different collections.

Comment: @GokalpAltun The OP specifically asked for populate in mongoose, removed the line regarding MongoDB joins